# android: google map loading issue

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using google map in my app , the code runs  on device perfectly but the map does not load ! I just see a white screen !  what's the problem ?

here is the code , please help !

```
public class MyMap extends MapActivity {
   private MapView map;
   private MapController controller;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      initMapView();
      initMyLocation();
   }

   /** Find and initialize the map view. */
   private void initMapView() {
      map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
      controller = map.getController();
      map.setSatellite(true);
      map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   }

   /** Start tracking the position on the map. */
   private void initMyLocation() {
      final MyLocationOverlay overlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
      overlay.enableMyLocation();
      //overlay.enableCompass(); // does not work in emulator
      overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            // Zoom in to current location
            controller.setZoom(8);
            controller.animateTo(overlay.getMyLocation());
         }
      });
      map.getOverlays().add(overlay);
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
      // Required by MapActivity
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you add your manifest file and xml file hear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your map api key in xml [here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)  is tutorial to get map api key

Answer (score 0):

Create your google map api key and pest in maplayout.xml

android:apiKey=" your api key"

which is freely avaliable